# How to make an inner join with @Query JPA?

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-data-jpa

I would like to make a query with @Query JPA and I don't know how to do it. I would like to return all the Varieties (Variedad) that correspond to the name (nombre) of a Species (Especie). Also, I would like to add a ContainingIgnoreCase to the @Query

**Familia**

```
public class Familia {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;
    private String nombre;
    private String linkImagen;
    
    private Date fechaRegistro = new Date();
    
    @Column(length=1000)
    private String descripcion;
    
    @Column(insertable = false, updatable = false) 
    private String dtype;
}
```

**Especie**

```
public class Especie extends Familia {

    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer diasGerminacionDesde;
    private Integer diasGerminacionHasta;
    private Integer distEntrePlantas;
    private Integer distEntreLineas;

    @ManyToOne
    private Familia familia;

    @JoinTable(name = "especie_mesesSiembra", 
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "especie_id"), 
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "mesSiembra_id"))

    @ManyToMany
    @OrderBy
    private Set<MesSiembra> mesesSiembra = new LinkedHashSet<>();

}
```

**Variedad**

```
public class Variedad extends Especie {
    
    @GeneratedValue

    @ManyToOne
    private Especie especie;
}
```

**Variedad controller**

```
@GetMapping(params= {"nombreEspecie"})
public Page<Variedad> listarTodosFiltradoPorNombreEspecie(String nombreEspecie, Pageable pagina) {
    return servicio.listarTodosFiltradoPorNombreEspecie(nombreEspecie, pagina);
}
```

**Variedad service**

```
public Page<Variedad> listarTodosFiltradoPorNombreEspecie(String nombreEspecie, Pageable pagina) {
    return repositorio.listarTodosFiltradoPorNombreEspecie(nombreEspecie, pagina);
}
```

**Variedad repository**

```
public interface VariedadRepositorio extends JpaRepository<Variedad, Integer>{

    @Query("select v from Variedad v "
            + "join Especie e"
            + "where v.dtype='Variedad' "
            + "and e.nombre=nombreEspecie"
            + "order by v.nombre asc")
    Page<Variedad> listarTodosFiltradoPorNombreEspecie(String nombreEspecie, Pageable pagina);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing a JPA you don't specify the joining entity. You simply reference the related property from the original entity.

Example:

```
@Query("select v from Variedad v "
        + "inner join v.especie e"
        + "where v.dtype='Variedad' "
        + "and e.nombre=nombreEspecie"
        + "order by v.nombre asc")
Page<Variedad> listarTodosFiltradoPorNombreEspecie(String nombreEspecie, Pageable pagina);
```

To perform a string comparison that is case insensitive you could use 'lower' and 'like'

```
where lower(v.dtype) like lower(concat('%', nombreEspecie,'%'))
```

I have not tested this so there might be a typo.